# Using Webhooks with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webhooks

I am unfamiliar with Webhooks but I feel like they are the right thing for my app.

I have the following documentation for [FluidSurveys webhook](http://docs.fluidsurveys.com/fluidsurveys/api/webhooks.html)

I understand how I can make the webhook through a `POST` request to their `API`, but I don't know how can I tell where the webhook is actually going to send the response.
Can I pass any subscription url I want? e.g. `https://www.myapp.com/test` and is that where `webhook` will send the data? Also, after the `webhook` is created I'm not sure how to ensure my Rails app will receive the response that is initiated.
I assume a controller method that corresponds with the url I provide to the webhook.

If I'm correct on the controller handling the webhook, what would that look like?

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: At the risk of being a jerk, "I am unfamiliar with `thing` but I feel like it is the right thing for me" seems like the wrong approach to technology choices. This question might be better posed as "I need to accomplish `goal`, what is the best solution?".

Answer (score 66, accepted):

**Webhooks** *hook* into your app via a **callback URL** you provide. This is just an action in one of your controllers that responds to **POST** requests and handles the webhook request. Every time something changes to the remote service, the remote service makes a request to the callback URL you provided, hence triggering the *action* code.

I'll exemplify with the **survey created** event. You start by defining a **callback** action for this event, where you handle the request coming from the webhook. As stated [here](http://docs.fluidsurveys.com/fluidsurveys/api/webhooks.html#creation-and-deletion) the webhook responds with the following body:

```
survey_creator_name=&survey_name=MADE+A+NEW+SURVEY&survey_creator_email=timothy@example.com&survey_url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fsurveys%2Fbob%2Fmade-a-new-survey%2F``
```

Let's leave the headers for now, they don't contain important information. The available body parameters (`survey_creator_name`, `survey_name` etc.) will reflect all details regarding the new survey available on the remote service. So let's write a **callback action** that handles this request:

```
class HooksController

  def survey_created_callback
    # If the body contains the survey_name parameter...
    if params[:survery_name].present?
      # Create a new Survey object based on the received parameters...
      survey = Survey.new(:name => params[:survey_name]
      survey.url = params[:survey_url]
      survey.creator_email = params[:survey_creator_email]
      survey.save!
    end

    # The webhook doesn't require a response but let's make sure
    # we don't send anything
    render :nothing => true
  end

end
```

Let's add the route for this (in `config/routes.rb`):

```
scope '/hooks', :controller => :hooks do
  post :survey_created_callback
end
```

This will enable the `POST /hooks/survey_created_callback` route.

Now you'll need to subscribe this **callback URL** to the Webhooks API. First you'll want to know [which hooks](http://docs.fluidsurveys.com/fluidsurveys/api/webhooks.html#getting-a-list-of-webhooks) are available to you. You do this by placing a GET request at `/api/v2/webhooks/`. In the response you'll find the *event name*, *survey* and *collector* parameters.

Finally, you [subscribe](http://docs.fluidsurveys.com/fluidsurveys/api/webhooks.html#post--api-v2-webhooks-subscribe-) to one of the previously listed hooks by placing a request to the `POST /api/v2/webhooks/subscribe/` URL with the following contents:

```
{
  "subscription_url": "http://your-absolute-url.com/hooks/survey_created_callback",
  "event": "[EVENT NAME FROM THE HOOKS LIST]",
  "survey": "[SURVEY FROM THE HOOKS LIST]",
  "collector": "[COLLECTOR FROM THE HOOKS LIST]"
}
```

The response to this will be a code `201` if the hook was created successfully, or code `409`, if a webhook for the same callback URL already exists. Or something else, if this went bad :)

You can now test the hook, by creating a survey on the remote service and then watch it getting replicated in your Rails app.

Hope this helps...

Comment: When you said "subscribe to a hook", did you mean craft a URL with the json content shown above and enter the URL into a browser's address bar?

Comment: @i.am.noob the endpoint to subscribe to a webhook is, in this case, a POST endpoint. when entering a URL in your browser's address bar you make a GET request. I'd suggest you to go a bit deeper in the differences between GET and POST requests (reading about PUT and DELETE wouldn't hurt either). but one big difference is that GET requests (usually) don't accept a body. that piece of JSON there should go into the request body (of the POST request).

Comment: So... use curl to do a POST request using terminal?

Comment: @i.am.noob yes, curl or any http library from your favourite programming language. you could also use a browser plugin like Postman (Chrome) to place POST requests.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and thorough answer, you're awesome!